# add random dates in 400K pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, faker

Trying to append a fourth column to the following dataframe of length `465017`.

```
     0        1     2
0   228055  231908  1
1   228056  228899  1
```

Running following syntax

```
x["Fake_date"]= fake.date(pattern="%Y-%m-%d", end_datetime=None)
```

returns

```
     0        1    2    Fake_date
0   228055  231908  1   1980-10-12
1   228056  228899  1   1980-10-12
```

but I want different random dates on `465017` rows for an instance,

```
      0       1    2    Fake_date
0   228055  231908  1   1980-10-11
1   228056  228899  1   1980-09-12
```

How do I randomize this?

Comment: What is `fake`?

Comment: pyhton package from faker import Faker
fake=Faker()

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without the `faker` package, you can do this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x["Fake_date"] = np.random.choice(pd.date_range('1980-01-01', '2000-01-01'), len(x))

>>> x
        0       1  2  Fake_date
0  228055  231908  1 1999-12-08
1  228056  228899  1 1989-01-25
```

replacing the 2 date strings in `pd.date_range()` with the minimum and maximum date that you want to choose random dates from