# pandas.DataFrame.loc: TypeError returned when trying to modify values of column based on datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a data frame that contains a column of dates and another column that I'd like to modify according to the date.  However when I try to do this using the .loc method, I get

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Could anyone please explain 1) why this error comes up - the dates are datetime objects, and 2) how I can modify the second column.  I include a MWE below.

Many thanks

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def random_dates(start, end, n, unit='D', seed=None):
    if not seed:  # from piR's answer
        np.random.seed(0)

    ndays = (end - start).days + 1
    return pd.to_timedelta(np.random.rand(n) * ndays, unit=unit) + start


start_date = pd.to_datetime('2010-01-01')
end_date   = pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'Names'])

N = 10
df['Date'] = random_dates(start_date, end_date, N)
df = df.assign(Names = ['A'] * N)

df.loc['Date' < DT(2015, 1, 1), 'Names'] = 'B'
```

(random_dates function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559078/generating-random-dates-within-a-given-range-in-pandas))

Answer (score 1):

Switch the line

```
df.loc['Date' < DT(2015, 1, 1), 'Names'] = 'B'
```

to

```
df.loc[df.Date < DT(2015, 1, 1), 'Names'] = 'B'
```

This would solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `df.loc` statement properly. For your particular logic, you want to change the values of column `Names` to "B" when a row's corresponding date is < `2015-1-1`. When you want to include any conditions in `df.loc`, the proper way to use it is like this:

```
df.loc[(df['Date'] < DT(2015, 1, 1)), 'Names'] = 'B'
```

For a detailed guide on how to use conditions with `df.loc`, you can refer this [link](https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-select-rows-by-multiple-label-conditions-with-pandas-loc-in-python)